I am starting to learn about C*-quantum groups, particularly finite q-groups. What are some best resources, books and surveys I can start with?
Some questions that baffle me are:
methods of constructing a quantum group, VNA and C*-algebraic quantum groups relationship, finding the dual of famous nonabelian finite groups, explicitly calculating the dual of famous quantum groups.

Thanks, @JPMcCarthy. These resources will get me started.

@TimonKolt I think this question is not perfectly formulated, but as I understand it, it is asking for a literature recommendation addressing the questions in the body. So it's really only one question - that for good references.

@MaoWao Yes, exactly. That is what I meant. I will be more careful next time formulating a question.

Maybe it should be closed as a duplicate.

If you are learning about finite quantum groups for the first time, I assume that it will be the first time that you will have come across Hopf Algebras. Look at Section 2.2 for a "derivation" of the Hopf algebra axioms. Slightly faster is Section 1.1.
Given what you said first, I would leave the relationships between the VNa and C*-approaches, and the dual of a compact quantum group until a little later.
Otherwise I would point you here (links updated). Any introductory text will treat the dual of a finite group (the cocommutative case).

Thank you, JP Mcarthy. This is very helpful.
